# Google maps autocomplete. How can I set language for results?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I'm using Google Maps and autocomplete for addresses https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete.

How I connect Google Maps:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
```

I need get suggested results (addresses) **only in english**. At this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete I didn't find a solution.

I can typing in any language:

[image]

Comment: In your example, you are using "Киев", but the user should _only_ be able to use "Kiev". Correct?

Comment: @bcdan yes, you are right.

Comment: If a user were searching for a place in Mexico, they would need to use Spanish words. If Spanish words were prohibited, the user would not be able to search for many place there. There are serious problems with this, and that is probably why Google does not have that option available, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think he means, when user put in "Киев", user can only see results that are english only. if that is the case, you can try to filter out all the non-english results before you display the places results. Sadly google maps places api does not tell you what language a particular entry is in, so you would have to do some regex operations on the formatted address.